# SQL Server: deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Tags: sql-server

I'm aware this error has been covered, it's more advice relating to the wider picture I'm after really.

I have an account restricted to just SELECT on a handful of tables in a database owned by a third party application. The idea being that we can safely query the odd thing here and there without having to request the third party make changes for us (they're not very responsive).

This has (ostensibly) been working fine until earlier today when I noticed an exception in the logs (see post title).

Given that the query was:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(ss, '01-01-1970 00:00:00', (SELECT MAX(CREATEDDATE) 
                                         FROM VISITS 
                                         WHERE CUSTID = 31))
```

And that `DBCC USEROPTIONS` tells me the isolation level is read committed, why should the above conflict with anything? I can understand it getting an outdated value, but why conflict on a committed-only read?

Anyway, what's worrying me more is what might be happening on the other end. What if the third party app is experiencing similar errors and nobody has noticed (they wouldn't in a hurry)?

Can anyone put my mind at rest about the other end (again, I'm only doing `SELECT`s), and possibly also advise on best practice in this sort of scenario? SQL concurrency isn't something I've had to worry too much about in the past.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of deadlock often has to do with the access path to the value in the table and indexes affected. The query above contains an aggregate (max) so at minimum (no pun intended) it will have to go *find* the max value among the rows for the requested customer. There may be an index that supports that. During the search, though, even if brief, the data needs to be locked against updates. At the same time an update query may come along accessing the data using a different sequence of indexes, and it needs an exclusive lock to allow updates. So yes, read committed isolation and just the right update and select can deadlock.

The best long term resolution is probably RCSI (Read Committed Snapshot Isolation) which allows reads to use "old" versions of rows instead of the live/hot value being modified in the table. If you have a third party app, though, then the vendor would have to test for and support that setting before you can turn it on. Don't just turn that on. It's a great feature but needs testing for specific apps. That said, the changes typically required are minimal or none, with some exceptions.

Failing that, a careful study of the deadlock graph from a real event like this at the server can yield a way to change the indexes, possibly, to prevent the deadlock.

Lastly, you can read uncommitted data instead, but with the consequence that it may not be 100% accurate all the time.

Comment: Thanks. Am I safe to assume with SELECTs only that I'm not getting in the way of the other app then?

Comment: No, you can't really assume that. You may want to monitor the SQL Server for all deadlocks (both from the app and from your selects) to be on the safe side.

Comment: @oneupdatecascade How do you monitor the deadlocks on the Sql Server to be able to debug these when they happen? Any pointers? I'm getting these deadlocks a couple times a week.

Comment: If you are on a current version of SQL Server the recommended way is to use the System Health Extended Events trace (or your own additional Extended Events trace. There's a good explanation here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2012/06/28/how-to-monitor-deadlocks-in-sql-server/